# Is there any way to replace your 1st level class feat?

Tags: feats, pathfinder-2e

If I do not like any of the 2nd level class feats available to me, I can intead pick an Archetype feat.
Is there a way to also do this for 1st level feats?

Preferably a solution that works for any class, but lacking that specific classes will do too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Casters don't generally choose a first level feat

So this point is mostly moot if you choose a caster class - Wizards, Sorcerers, Clerics, Druids, etc. don't generally get a 1st level class feat, unless one of their 1st level choices gives it to them (like the Druid Orders in core give a specific class feat, or the Universalist Wizard gives a choice of 1st level Wizard Feat).

### For non-casters, you cannot swap out your first level class feat

There's simply no option or rule that would allow you to exchange it for something else. If you don't want any of the things a non-caster class offers at first level, there's no way to choose something else in its place. Though, the first level class feats for all the classes that currently exist are pretty descriptive of what the class can build towards and do in general; if you don't want any of a given class' 1st-level feats, you may want to look towards picking a different class.

Comment: So there are 1st level Cleric feats, just no way to take them on 1st level beside Natural Ambition?

Comment: @András Correct. You can take them at higher levels or via Natural Ambition (and possibly similar things, if/when they come out). There's also the distinct possibility that Clerics eventually get a Doctrine whose 1st benefit is a class feat choice (a la Universalist Wizard). And the Doctrines do give a feat, you just don't get to choose it with the current ones - Domain Initiate for Cloistered Cleric, and sometimes Deadly Simplicity for Warpriests.

Answer (score 2):

> If I do not like any of the 2nd level class feats available to me, I can intead pick an Archetype feat.
>   Is there a way to also do this for 1st level feats?

Yes ... depending on what exactly you mean - but not yet for 1st level class feats.

The [Ancient Elf heritage](https://2e.aonprd.com/Heritages.aspx?ID=34) from the Lost Omens Character Guide gives you an archetype at level 1, while the Human options [Natural Ambition](http://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=70), and [General Training](http://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=68) let you swap an ancestry feat for a class feat or skill feat respectively.

If instead you are asking if there was a universal rule that let you say pick a general feat instead of a class feat, or a skill feat instead of an ancestry feat, then I'm afraid the answer is no.

---

> 'But not yet for class feats'

Paizo have announced that Class Archetypes, which are closer to PF1 style archetypes (relative to what we currently have) will debut in the Advanced Character Guide, which is due out at GenCon next year - which is unfortunately most of a year away (If I recall correctly, they have announced that there will be 60 pages of archetypes). However these have the potential to do what you want. They are described in the [CRB under Class Archetypes](http://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=169).

Apologies that this part of my answer is of little use right now.